# Get the selected option key in Actions on Google NodeJS library v2

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

My action for the Google Assistant presents the user with a list of options using a `Carousel`. Each item presented in the carousel has an option key.

In v1 of the Actions on Google NodeJS SDK I used `app.getSelectedOption()` to access the key of the selected option in the intent which handled the option selection.

How can I access this key in v2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in the [source code of the new SDK](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/0594c8f28a72e7811f90053659d4de17539c8c90/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/question/option/carousel.ts#L105).

The third parameter of the handler function will be the option key:

```
app.intent('Get Option', (conv, input, option) => {
  console.log(option) // This will log the key
}
```